# How to get correct date from a string in Java using SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I am writing an application and have to convert a string into date. The string will have weeks, days and other information, and finally calculate time difference in minutes from that date to current time as shown below. With the code I have, I was expecting to have the "past" object as certain calendar date that was "13 weeks, 2 days, 16 hours, 42 minutes" from current time but what I found surprised me (date object is Tue Mar 24 15:54:00 CST 1970 as of now). Can some one please explain me why my code doesn't work and how to fix that? I referred to the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but it didn't help me much.

```java
        String givenStr = "13 weeks, 2 days, 16 hours, 42 minutes";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("w 'weeks', u 'days', H 'hours', m 'minutes'");
        try {
            Date past =  format.parse(givenStr);
            Date now = new Date();
            Long minutes = (now.getTime()-past.getTime())/(60*1000);
            System.out.printf("Date: %s Minutes: %s\n", past, minutes);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            //DO STH
        }
```

Comment: Dates are not durations.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does your string always contain exactly those four units (weeks, days, hours, minutes)? Are the plural forms used also when the counts are 1 (`1 weeks, 1 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes`)?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use [standard ISO 8601 formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) for your span-of-time text: `P13W2DT16H42M`.

Use modern date-time classes found in the *java.time* framework and in the *ThreeTen-Extra* library: [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html), and [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Instant
.now()
.plus(
    PeriodDuration
    .parse(
        "P" + 
        "13 weeks, 2 days, 16 hours, 42 minutes"
        .replace( " weeks, " , "W" )
        .replace( " days, " , "DT" )
        .replace( " hours, " , "H" )
        .replace( " minutes" , "M" )
    )
)
```

> 2019-08-18T18:30:42.007034Z

## Details

You are conflating two different concepts:

- a **moment**, a point on the timeline
- a **span-of-time** unattached to the timeline

## Moment

For a moment, we no longer use the `java.util.Date` class. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the `java.time.Instant` class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

## Span-of-time

Your input string does *not* represent a moment. It represents a span-of-time.

For a span in terms of years-month-days, we use the `Period` class. For a span in terms of hours-minutes-seconds, we use the `Duration`.

## `PeriodDuration`

You can combine the two concepts using the [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class found in the external library built from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. But you should think twice about this. It rarely makes practical sense to combine the two granularities.

But, if you insist, let's give it a go.

First, alter your input string to use standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. In this format, the `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates the coarser granularity from the finer.

```
String input = "P" + "13 weeks, 2 days, 16 hours, 42 minutes".replace( " weeks, " , "W" ).replace( " days, " , "DT" ).replace( " hours, " , "H" ).replace( " minutes" , "M" ) ;
```

> P13W2DT16H42M

Parse that new input as a `PeriodDuration`.

```
PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.parse( input );
```

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

> now.toString(): 2019-05-17T01:48:42.007034Z

Add your period-duration to determine a future moment.

```
Instant later = now.plus( pd );
```

> later.toString(); 2019-08-18T18:30:42.007034Z

If you want a past moment rather than a future moment, call [`Instant::minus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#minus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)).

```
Instant earlier = now.minus( pd ) ;
```

### Minutes elapsed

If you want a total number of minutes elapsed between those two moments, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , later ) ;
long minutesTotal = d.toMinutes() ;
```

> minutesTotal: 134922

### Time zone

If you want to work with a moment as perceived through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), use the `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId` classes. Call the same named `plus`/`minus` methods as seen above.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZoneDateTime earlier = now.minus( pd ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).